# Как правильно вывести значение в градиенте?

Tags: angular

сейчас percentage не выводится

```html
<div class="test" [ngStyle]="{{`linear-gradient(90deg, blue {{percentage}}%, red {{percentage}} )`}}">click</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант использовать вместо [ngStyle] просто style, а внутри ковычек

```
{{'linear-gradient(90deg, blue ' + percentage + '%, red ' + percentage + '%)'}}
```